# enclose contents of cell in brackets, ms excel, format

Tags: excel, numbers, format, excel-2010, parentheses

I would like to format the contents of my MS excel cell so that every number (all the entries are numeric) is enclosed in brackets like so:

```
[-23.293], [23.394]
```

I used custom format and specified the format as `"["00.000"]"`.  However, this produces entries like this:

```
-[23.293], [23.394]
```

I cannot figure out how to fix this. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

specify the custom format as `"["00.000"]";"["-00.000"]"`. 
The second parameter is the way negative numbers are displayed. If you add a third option, it's for 0 values.